# How to loop through a datatable to copy over to another sheet with Macros Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a certain column in a spreadsheet and transfer that information over to another spreadsheet. How can I do this?

For example, I want to have my current macro do repeat for all cells in a certain column, as you can see here:

```vb
Sub Test()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A2").Select 'I want to select all values in column A, starting at row 2
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("C2").Select 'I want everything to be pasted in column C, starting at row 2
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2")`

Comment: I get an error saying `expected expression` when I use `:=`

Comment: BigBen answer is one line, not two line

Comment: @Rosetta the format of the comment is wrapping it onto two lines, but yes it is one line.

Comment: Yes, I typed it on 2 separate lines

Comment: Make it one line.

Comment: Oh it is one line?

Comment: This worked great thank you, if you want to type it as an answer to this question i can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy/paste the entire range from row two to the last row.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2")
```

To be thorough, best to qualify the `Rows` call with the worksheet as well:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).Copy _
       Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2")
```

The  `_` is the line continuation here.